# C calling free on not allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, free

Why this program doesn't crash, is it undefined behaviour ?

```
int main()
{
   char* c;
   if (c) {
        printf("called free\n");
        free (c);
   }
   else {
        printf("not called free\n");
   }

   printf("not crashed\n");
   c = strdup("someString");

   if (c) {
        printf("called free\n"); 
        free(c);
        c = NULL;  // why is this needed for last if (c) 
   }
   
   if (c) {
        free(c);
   }
   printf("still not crashed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

1. Is any possibility that this program will ever crash ?
2. Should I always make such a if (c) verification before I call free on char* ?
3. why without c=NULL free is called ?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour includes behaviour that appears to work correctly. If it would always crash, that would be defined behaviour.

Comment: Side note: When your program crashes, then all data in the output buffer that has not been flushed will probably be lost (i.e. will never be printed). Therefore, before doing something that will potentially crash the program, I suggest that you flush the output buffer using `fflush(stdout);` to ensure that all output is printed to the screen beforehand. Or better: Print all diagnostic output to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, for example using `fprintf(stderr,"not crashed");`. In contrast to `stdout`, `stderr` is generally unbuffered and therefore does not have the problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some background: there are three kinds of pointer values:

1. null pointers: either because you explicitly initialized to NULL, or because it was a global (or static) variable which is automatically initialized to a null pointer.
2. valid pointers: a pointer that you have explicitly set to point to something: either by using `&`, or by calling `malloc` or `realloc` or `strdup`, and as long as the pointer has not become invalid.
3. invalid pointers: pointers that are local ("automatic") variables that have not been initialized; pointers that were set (using `&`) to point to local variables in functions ("stack frames") that are no longer active; pointers that were once allocated using `malloc` or the others, but that have since been deallocated using `free`, or reallocated using `realloc`.

You can tell if a pointer is in category 1 using an ordinary comparison: `if(p == NULL)`, `if(p != NULL)`.

But the key point is that *there is no programmatic way of distinguishing between pointer values in categories 2 and 3*.  That is, there is no way to write `if(valid(p))` or `if(invalid(p))`.

So the only way to avoid using invalid pointers is to keep track, yourself, somehow, of which pointers are valid and which are not.  One strategy for doing this, pretty widely recommended as a good habit, is to set pointer variables to NULL whenever you know they're invalid.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879760#49880979) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57436495#57436746).

Now, for some specific answers to your code and questions:

> `int main()`
> `{`
>     `char* c;`

So `c` is a local variable.  Since it is not initialized, it is unquestionably *in*valid (that is, category 3).

> `if (c) {`
>         `printf("called free\n");`
>         `free (c);`
>    `}`
>    `else {`
>         `printf("not called free\n");`
>    `}`

This is a strange piece of code.  It seems to acknowledge the possibility that the uninitialized pointer `c` might reliably start out as a null pointer, which as I just said is not the case.  Also, this code is actually arranged, if anything, to *maximize* the possibility of a crash.  If, by chance, `c` starts out as a null pointer, `free` is not called — but it turns out that `free` is guaranteed to behave gracefully — by quietly doing nothing — if it's passed a null pointer.  Only if `c` is non-null — meaning that it's guaranteed to be invalid — is it handed to `free`, where it's virtually guaranteed to cause trouble.

> `c = NULL;  // why is this needed for last if (c)`

As mentioned, it's a good habit to set pointers to `NULL` after freeing them.  A null pointer is testably invalid, while a non-NULL but freed pointer is undetectably invalid.

> 1. Is any possibility that this program will ever crash ?

Yes, it is quite likely to crash, since if tries to free invalid, uninitialized pointer, and (without that "why is this needed?" line), it frees a pointer twice.

If you ran this code, and it *didn't* crash, that's kind of interesting, but it doesn't prove anything.  Code that exhibits undefined behavior, such as trying to use the value of an uninitialized or otherwise invalid pointer, is not guaranteed to work.  But it is not guaranteed not to work.  "Undefined behavior" means that *anything* can happen, including code that appears to magically work.  Undefined behavior does not mean that code is guaranteed to crash, or anything like that.

> 2. Should I always make such a `if (c)` verification before I call `free` on `char*` ?

You can, but I don't think it does what you think it does.

It's not necessary, because as I mentioned, if you have a pointer that's already null, it's harmless to call `free` on it.  So the test, in and of itself, doesn't protect you from anything.

If you thought that the `if(c)` test *did* protect you from something, like by making sure you don't accidentally free an invalid pointer, it's not necessarily any good for that at all — *unless* you're religious about always setting pointers to `NULL` when you know they've become invalid.

Comment: Another issue is that even if one constructed a malloc/free implementation so that `free` would harmlessly do nothing if passed an invalid pointer (which would be possible), there would be no way of knowing whether calling `free()` with an unknown pointer value might free a region of storage which is going to be used for some other purpose, thus causing a use-after-free scenario which cannot be practically trapped.

Comment: Even if a system could trap any attempts to access something that isn't a valid allocated region, passing an unknown pointer to `free()` between two other allocation requests may result in the second request yielding a pointer to the same storage as the first.  Attempts to write the storage returned by the first allocation may stomp the storage pointed to by the second, and vice versa, but such accesses would not be trapped because they would all be accesses to seemingly valid storage.

Answer (score 2):

> Is any possibility that this program will ever crash ?

1. Yes, there is. Your code invokes undefined behaviour;

> **behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or
> of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no
> requirements.¹**

Anything can happen, and that includes a crash.

---

> Should I always make such a if (c) verification before I call free on
> char* ?

No, a call to `free()` with a `NULL` pointer constant is a NOP, i.e. no operation is performed. So it's unnecessary.

> **If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs.²**

---

> why without c=NULL free is called ?

Because the `free()` function doesn't set the original pointer to `NULL`. `c` is still pointing to the same memory location, but it is invalid for `c` to access it anymore.

> **The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be
> deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation.³**

Without setting `c` to `NULL`, a subsequent call to `free()` would be freeing already freed memory, which also invokes undefined behaviour.

> **Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned
> by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated
> by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined.⁴**

### Footnotes:

[1] - [2] - [3] - [4] - The C11 Standard, 7.22.3.3 The `free` function.

Comment: char* c; is not automatically points to NULL, is it ?

Comment: @lkmlkm: The initial value of `c` will be [indeterminate](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.2), which means that it may happen to be `NULL` or it may happen to be another value or it may not be a valid value at all (i.e. it may have a trap representation).

Comment: No, pointers aren't automatically initialized to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```
   char* c;
   if (c) {
        printf("called free\n");
        free (c);
   }
   else {
        printf("not called free\n");
   }
```

invokes undefined behavior because the pointer `c` is uninitialized.

As for this code snippet

```
   if (c) {
        printf("called free\n"); 
        free(c);
        c = NULL;  // why is this needed for last if (c) 
   }
   
   if (c) {
        free(c);
   }
```

then if the pointer `c` will not be set to `NULL`

```
c = NULL;  // why is this needed for last if (c)
```

then in the next if statement there will be an attempt to free already freed memory that again invokes undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior does not necessary crash a program. For example in the first code snippet the pointer `c` can be set internally to `NULL`.

Pay attention that you may call the function `free` for a null pointer. In this case no action occurs.

Comment: char* c; fee(c); free(c); also undefined behaviour and might crash ? I didn't see crash for such code only when there was actually memory to be freed and free() was called multiple times.

Comment: @lkmlkm Of course it is undefined behavior. The code can be executed successfully if by accident the pointer c is set to NULL. You may call free for a null pointer.